# IFrame content is showing as blank while printing the whole page

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, iframe

I have asp.net page, in that page i have lot of design, and i have put one Iframe control. I am loading pdf in iframe. When i print the page, all the designs in the page are showing whereas the Iframe content showing as blank?
Can anyone suggest how to print the iframe content along with the page design?

I have asp.net page, in that page i have lot of design, and i have put one Iframe control. I am loading pdf in iframe. When i print the page, all the designs in the page are showing whereas the Iframe content showing as blank?
Can anyone suggest how to print the iframe content along with the page design?

Answer (score 0):

The reason we use frames such as <Embed an <Object in <iFrame is so we can run one binary application/pdf window inside another binary application/html window.

Thus, ***if it's allowed***, we print one or the other that are present in their own window.

It is often the case that a pdf is not reloaded into the browser after its downloaded by the inner framed application.

So you can print a web page natively by both applications as two pages, but thats not much use as an answer to your question.

The only reasonable solution is to capture the combined screen output, and for that we can press print screen or take a screenshot with yet another binary application, such as the operating system driving the screen.